# Typescript 'number' cannot be used to index type on object constant

Tags: typescript, types

I have an object constant that i wish to type up. For brevity, let's say it looks like this:

```
const obj = {
    outer1: {
        inner1: ['a', 'b'],
        inner2: ['c', 'd'],
    },
    outer2: {
        inner3: ['e', 'f'],
    },
} as const
```

This object is central to my application, so I wish to type up several elements of it for validation app-wide. I have no problem restricting the outer and inner keys as so:

```
type ObjType = typeof obj
type OuterKeys = keyof ObjType
type InnerKeys<KOuter extends OuterKeys> = keyof ObjType[KOuter]
```

So far so good. Now I want to create a type that restricts values to the selected outer and inner key. For example, I wish to generate a type using generics that would become `'a' | 'b'` for outer1/inner1. I start by extending the above types like so:

```
type Inner<
    KOuter extends OuterKeys,
    KInner extends keyof ObjType[KOuter]
> = ObjType[KOuter][KInner]
```

Which produces the type `readonly ['a', 'b']`, not `a | b`. So i further the above type to create this effect by doing

```
type AOrB = Inner<'outer1', 'inner1'>[number]
```

which works perfectly. However, when it comes to blending this into the type itself:

```
type Inner<
    KOuter extends OuterKeys,
    KInner extends keyof ObjType[KOuter]
> = ObjType[KOuter][KInner][number]
```

I receive the error `Type 'number' cannot be used to index type [constant representation of obj type]`. Why does this happen - and can i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think typescript can't infer that your type results in an array due to lazy type inference. As far as I am aware, typescript only evaluates the parts of a generic it has to for performance reasons. When you write

```
type AOrB = Inner<'outer1', 'inner1'>[number]
```

you force the compiler to actually check what type is behind `obj.outer1.inner1` and it notices it's an array. But if you write

```
type Inner<
    KOuter extends OuterKeys,
    KInner extends keyof ObjType[KOuter]
> = ObjType[KOuter][KInner][number]
```

there are only generics it doesn't have to evaluate yet, because you didn't specify 'outer1' or 'inner1' it doesn't check what type is behind `obj.outer1.inner1` and then falsely warns you, that you can't use index types. But you can trick the compiler in believing that the result is an array with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```
type Inner<
    KOuter extends OuterKeys,
    KInner extends ObjKeys<KOuter>
> = ObjType[KOuter][KInner] extends readonly any[] ? ObjType[KOuter][KInner][number] : never;
```

With the conditional type the compiler is sure that `ObjType[KOuter][KInner]` must be an array, even without evaluating the generic, because otherwise it would land in the else part, which we know never happens. Its a bit hacky though.

Edit: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=75&pln=10&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHcCuUApgE4CMAXBtrjQJZhgkUwDaA5AIZsA0Mb8bALrdqNHPUbEATJXbAefACZCRNAL6rcIAiRlUxuCSQDMstoQVsAZitEwNmNTA4QYoSFADcmTFACeAA6EMADySAAqgcFo-kEgVnBI3rHBITrEANKEfq5oANbZ8aERUclRxYhZOQA8GTCEAB5EYIquaUSZ2RAAfKgwBX5FYYiRQSwZgt6%205QCSDCS17ST1TYQtbelVELwZc5Irza0VW4vp3b1ow6OE40vEguN7JIIHa0fEhByK4AA2fs5gPwsQR2AD8FWut3SD1283uLDAeAAtvBnnZKIwAG4kKYpZwgYjwPpPYjVNjaDqkSxGMhsGAAHz4NKkbG6nhgAHoOTAAEQcHkM3nwAWMnnAEW8xQ8oA)

Comment: Your conditional type works similarly to the [`Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union), which is what I often use in cases like this where the compiler loses track of constraints.  [playground](https://tsplay.dev/N5EeVN)

Comment: Also, this issue seems to be caused by a compiler bug, see [microsoft/TypeScript#27709](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27709) or [microsoft/TypeScript#28269](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28269).

Comment: Good to know it's a bug - wasn't sure if I was just trying to 'hack' the language or was doing something wrong. I've used your solution and it works fine, using `Extract ` to clean it up a touch. Thank you both!